# Mockito for Spring JPA Specifiction API does not execute the dynamic query entirely

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have the following Service class with dynamic query.

```
public class CarService {

    public Page<Cars> getAllCars(CarRequest request, ,, String carCarrier, String carNumber,Pageable pageRequest){
       String userCarrier = request.getSubCarrier();
       Specification <Car> carSpecification = null;
       carSpecification = getCarDetails(request, carCarrier, carNumber);
       return carRepository.findAll(carSpecification, pageRequest);
   }

    public Specification<Car> getCarDetails(CarRequest request, String carCarrier, String carNumber) {
        System.out.println("I am in query");
        return (Root<Car> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {
            System.out.println("I am executing query");
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getCarColor())) {
                predicates.add(cb.and(cb.equal(root.get(“carColor”), request.getCarColor())));
            }

            if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(carCarrier)) {
                predicates.add(cb.and(root.get("carCarrier”),carCarrier)));
            }

            if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(carNumber)) {
                predicates.add(cb.and(cb.equal(root.get("carNumber"), carNumber)));

            }
            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));

        };
    }
}
```

Below is my Test class where i am trying to test the dynamic query.

```
public class CarServiceTest {
@Mock
private CarService carService;

@Test
public void test_cars() {
    Pageable pageRequest = new PageRequest(0,20);
    CarRequest request = new CarRequest();
    request.setCarColor(“Red”);
    request.setCarMake(“Nissan”);
    when(carRepository.findAll(Mockito.any(Specification.class), Mockito.eq(pageRequest)))
            .thenReturn(Mockito.mock(Page.class));

    Assert.assertNotNull(carService.getAllCars(request, pageRequest));

    }

}
```

The above test case works but it just enters getCarDetails and prints the first line " I am in query" and returns. It does not go further ahead to check the conditional clauses in the query.

I also tried calling the method directly from test class as

```
carService.getCarDetails(carRequest. "ABC", “A123”);
```

Still the same result. I have recently started with Mockito so i am not sure if i am missing something here which is causing this behavior.

How can i make sure all my lines are executed from code coverage perspective.

Comment: That will throw a null pointer for CarService when i try to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Specification` is functional interface and you returning function which will be called by spring under the hood (after when you pass it to suitable repository method). In test you mock that repostiory method so there is no chance to execute that returned function.

In `Specification` case this function is called `toPredicate()`

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.java#L104

Comment: As i mentioned even if i call the method directly from test class i face same issue.                       
carService.getCarDetails(carRequest. "ABC", “A123”);                                                                                                                 Even this line of code has the same behavior.                                                                 Assert.assertNotNull(carService.getAllCars(request, pageRequest));

Comment: `carService.getCarDetails(carRequest. "ABC", “A123”).toPredicate(null, null, null)` in this case you will call method which spring calls internally, ofcourse spring passes sutiable objects (`Root<Car> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb`) as arguments to this method instead of nulls. If you call it like that console will print `"I am executing query"` and later it will throw nullponiter because we passed arguments which are null, but I hope after you will catch how functional interfaces works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped.